# Get sum of fields using filter

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
AllNews        Article 
 ------       -----------
|id    | --> | article_id|
 ------       -----------
| date |     | views     |
 ------       -----------
             | id        |
              -----------
```

All I want is to get sum of **views** for all articles between two dates for each date

```py
articles = []
all_news = AllNews.query.filter(AllNews.date.between(date1, date2)).all()
for i in all_news:
    articles += Article.query.filter_by(article_id=i.id).all()
```

Dunno what to do after this. How to filter **articles** by date and get sum of **views** for each date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, think it out in SQL. That would be a simple join, like

```
SELECT AllNews.id, SUM(Article.views) FROM AllNews, Article WHERE
AllNews.id = Article.article_id GROUP BY AllNews.id
```

right?

Now, I am not familiar with flask-sqlalchemy, but from what I gather from
the docs you would do something like:

```
from yourapplication import db
q = db.session.query(AllNews.id, func.sum(Article.views)).filter(
    AllNews.id == Article.article_id,
).group_by(AllNews.id)

for (article_id, count) in q:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. ```db.session.query(func.sum(Article.views)).filter(AllNews.id == Article.acticle_id, AllNews.date.between(date1, date2),).group_by(AllNews.date).order_by(AllNews.date).all()``` - that's the answer